# SQLite, Objective C: method returns int max value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

```
-(int)countTheNumberOfDublicatesForType:(int)typeID
{
NSInteger quantity=0;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:user_data];
sqlite3* database = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlQuery=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT COUNT(refID)\
                                         FROM dublicates\
                                         WHERE typeREF=%i",typeID);

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlQuery,-1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1,typeID);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            quantity = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_free((char*)sqlQuery);
        sqlite3_close(database);
}
else
{
    //
}

return quantity;
}
```

The math in this method returns the max value of int. Where's the mistake and how to manage it the way it would return the real values from db? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: returns the nums like 169626256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no error handling, you are binding to a nonexistent parameter, the code is indented wrong, and you are reading with a wrong data type.

Use something like this:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_errmsg(database); // log or print this
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return 0;
}
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                       "SELECT COUNT(refID) FROM dublicates WHERE typeREF=?",
                       -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_errmsg(database); // log or print this
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return 0;
}
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, typeID);
if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_ROW)
    sqlite3_errmsg(database); // log or print this
else
    quantity = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Is there any restriction regarding return time for methods working with sqlite databases. Looks like when I call this meth in other class it expects a NSMutableArray as its return type. See edit.

Comment: There is no relation between the method signature and the dataase. The method uses whatever return type you declare for it.